# Two Hausdorff Compactifications are equivalent iff the sets of bounded continuous real valued functions in X which extend to Y and Z coincide.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(g, Y)$ and $(h, Z)$ be two Hausdorff compactifications of $X$.
We have that $(g, Y)$ is equivalent to $(h, Z)$ if $\exists \text{ homeomorphism } \pi : Z \to Y$ such that $\pi \circ h = g$ by definition.

If this is the case, then if $f$ extends to $Y$ so there is a continuous $F:Y \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $F \circ g = f$ we see that $F \circ \pi$ extends $f$ to $Z$. Similarly the symmetrical case, so we have that if $(h, Z)$ and $(g, Y)$ are equivalent then the sets of bounded continuous real valued functions on $X$ which extend $Y$ and $Z$ coincide.

I am really struggling to show the converse. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you understand by "$(g, Y)$ is a compactification"? That $g:X\to Y$, $g(X)$ is a dense subset of $Y$ and $g$ is a homeomorphism onto image? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, to me, a compactification $(g, Y)$ is such that $Y$ is Hausdorff, compact, $g(X)$ is dense in $Y$ and $g$ is a homeomorphic embedding.

Comment: The only assumption on $X$ is that it is Hausdorff?

Comment: A space $X$ has such a compactification iff it is Tychonoff. Since if $X$ is homeomorphic to subspace of compact Hausdorff $Y$ then $Y$ is Normal (compact+Hausdorff) hence Tychonoff, and Tychonoff is preserved by subspaces.

Comment: Conversely if $X$ is Tychonoff we can use the embedding Lemma on all continuous functions functions to embed $h: X \to [0 , 1]^{\kappa}$ for some $\kappa$. Then $(h, cl( h(X) ))$ is a Hausdorff compactification. Where $cl$ denotes the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedding is the key to answer your question. For any space $A$ let $C(A)$ denote the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of continuous bounded real-valued functions on $A$. We can endow it with the $\sup$-norm, but that is irrelevant here.

The embedding $g : X \to Y$ induces the "restriction" $g^\ast : C(Y) \to C(X), g^\ast(\varphi) = \varphi \circ g$ which is a homomorphism of algebras. Define

$$C(X,g) = g^\ast(C(Y)). $$

This is the set of continuous bounded real-valued functions on $X$ which "extend" to $Y$. Since $g(X)$ is dense in $Y$, extensions are unique so that $g^\ast : C(Y) \to C(X,g)$ is an isomorphism. Let $P = \mathbb{R}^{C(X,g)}$ denote the product of copies $\mathbb{R}_\psi$ of the real line indexed by the set of all $\psi \in C(X,g)$. Define

$$u_g : Y \to P, u_g(y) = (\psi'(y))_{\psi \in C(X,g)} ,$$

where $g^\ast(\psi') =\psi$. Then $u_g$ is continuous since $p_\psi \circ u_g  = \psi'$ is continuous for all projections $p_\psi : P \to \mathbb{R}_\psi = \mathbb{R}$. Moreover $u_g$ is an injection because for any two distinct $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ there is a continuous $\varphi : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(y_1 ) \ne \varphi(y_2)$ (now take $\psi = g^\ast(\varphi)$). Therefore $u_g$ is an embedding because $Y$ is compact. By construction

$$g' = u_g \circ g : X \to P$$

is an embedding such that $\overline{g'(X)} = u_g(Y)$. For $x \in X$ we obtain

$$g'(x) = u(g(x)) = (\psi'(g(x)))_{\psi \in C(X,g)} = (\psi(x))_{\psi \in C(X,g)} .$$

Now consider $h : X \to Z$. By assumption we have $C(X,g) = C(X,h)$. We therefore obtain an embedding $u_h : Z \to P$ such that $\overline{h'(X)} = u_h(Z)$, where $h' = u_h \circ h$. But $g'= h'$ so that $u_g(Y) = u_h(Z)$ and $\pi = u_h^{-1} \circ u_g : Y \to Z$ is the desired homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for this!